# Simulations of Poisson Distributions with different sample sizes and lambdas

Tags: r, for-loop, nested, simulation, poisson

Let's start with a statistical model, X where X is a random Poisson distribution with parameter
k - lambda with k being a constant

X ~ Pois(k - lambda)

Now,assume that k = 20. How do I create a function or make use of for loops to run a simulation
where we have different values of `lambda <- c(2, 4, 8, 16)` and each lambda has different sample sizes, n = [1,25] (from n = 1 to n = 25 ).

```
n <- 1:10
k <- 20 
lambda <- c(2, 4, 8, 16)
result <- rpois(n, k - lambda)
result
```

The output:

```
28 12 13 1 13 16 16 3 12 15
```

Now obviously, my code is wrong because it is not giving me the right output. For any lambda values there should be output for each sample size from n=1, n=2, n=3 and up to n = 25.
My idea is to use a double for loop in order to create this. A for loop for the changing sample size,n and another for loop for the changing lambda values but I'm not too sure how to implement this.

The expected output should be something like this. For lambda = 8,

```
11
12,11
13,11,14
11,14,14,14
......
10 9 13 13 13 11 8 17 10 11 13 11 17 13 9 8 13 15 10 10 15 14 14 15 9
```

Comment: Why didn’t you use a for loop for one parameter and the warp that code in another for loop? Search on nested for-loop. Likely to have been asked and answered.

Comment: I was thinking of doing a for loop inside another for loop but I can't seem to implement it properly. Could you show an example of what you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `Vectorize` `rpois` and put it in `outer`.

```
n <- 1:10
k <- 20 
lambdas <- c(2, 4, 8, 16)

set.seed(42)
res <- outer(n, k - lambdas, Vectorize(rpois)) |> apply(2, as.list)
```

### Gives

```
res |> setNames(paste0('lambda_', lambdas))
# $lambda_2
# $lambda_2[[1]]
# [1] 11
# 
# $lambda_2[[2]]
# [1] 16 16
# 
# $lambda_2[[3]]
# [1] 16 23 17
# 
# $lambda_2[[4]]
# [1] 19 14 18 13
# 
# $lambda_2[[5]]
# [1] 23 12 17 17 14
# 
# $lambda_2[[6]]
# [1] 13 14 12 13 13 15
# 
# $lambda_2[[7]]
# [1] 13 18 24 13 10 15 21
# 
# $lambda_2[[8]]
# [1] 17 33 14 19 16 23 19 12
# 
# $lambda_2[[9]]
# [1] 15 21 10 16 15 19 28 23 17
# 
# $lambda_2[[10]]
# [1] 28 20 22 29 17 16 17 15 18 21
# 
# 
# $lambda_4
# $lambda_4[[1]]
# [1] 15
# 
# $lambda_4[[2]]
# [1] 15 17
# 
# $lambda_4[[3]]
# [1] 19 11 14
# 
# $lambda_4[[4]]
# [1] 16 18 18 15
# 
# $lambda_4[[5]]
# [1] 15 13 16 11 18
# 
# $lambda_4[[6]]
# [1] 11 16 15 23 12 18
# 
# $lambda_4[[7]]
# [1] 15 10 18 14 12 15 13
# 
# $lambda_4[[8]]
# [1] 20 14 20 22 19 11 17 20
# 
# $lambda_4[[9]]
# [1]  9 22 15 16 18 18 13 20 14
# 
# $lambda_4[[10]]
# [1] 19 14 22 14 19 15 17 22 21 15
# 
# 
# $lambda_8
# $lambda_8[[1]]
# [1] 13
# 
# $lambda_8[[2]]
# [1] 15 12
# 
# $lambda_8[[3]]
# [1] 17 11 14
# 
# $lambda_8[[4]]
# [1] 10  7  8  8
# 
# $lambda_8[[5]]
# [1] 20  8 13 11 12
# 
# $lambda_8[[6]]
# [1]  7 14 16 14 13 10
# 
# $lambda_8[[7]]
# [1] 13 10 11 15 13 12 11
# 
# $lambda_8[[8]]
# [1] 15 16  8  8  9 16 13 13
# 
# $lambda_8[[9]]
# [1]  7  9  6  9  6  4 12 13 26
# 
# $lambda_8[[10]]
# [1] 12  9  8 10 13 12 11 18 10 10
# 
# 
# $lambda_16
# $lambda_16[[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# $lambda_16[[2]]
# [1] 2 4
# 
# $lambda_16[[3]]
# [1] 3 6 6
# 
# $lambda_16[[4]]
# [1] 1 6 3 5
# 
# $lambda_16[[5]]
# [1] 2 4 7 4 7
# 
# $lambda_16[[6]]
# [1] 5 5 6 7 2 2
# 
# $lambda_16[[7]]
# [1] 2 6 6 3 4 4 3
# 
# $lambda_16[[8]]
# [1] 3 7 3 1 5 5 2 1
# 
# $lambda_16[[9]]
# [1] 3 0 4 7 3 3 4 2 3
# 
# $lambda_16[[10]]
# [1]  3  7  7  5  5 11  4  2  2  6
```

Comment: Hey Jay. Thanks for the help!  Do you perhaps have a more elementary solution?  One that is probably not as efficient but works just as intended. Once again, thank you Jay !

Comment: Vectorize is just window dressing for an ‘mapply’ loop.